# Rails:-location.Href not working in project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie on javascript and was implementing a loader in the project..

I have used the below code for the implementation of loader but it is not working:-

```
 var url = "http://localhost:3500/#!/Movies";
<script>
    $(function(){                                            //Loader implementation
        if (location.href==url){

            $(window).ready(function(){
                $('#loadIndicator1').fadeOut(1000);
                return false;
            });

        }
    });


</script>
```

I am calling the loadindicator in the code as:-

```
<ul>
    <li id="loadIndicator1" style="position:absolute ;top:50%;left:50%;z-index:99999;"></li>
  </ul>
```

I am not very sure why this is giving an issue.I am using `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` and `jqueryui-1.10.2.js`

Also when I hover on location..I get `unresolved variable location`.Please help me with this.

Comment: why you need window.ready?

Comment: @CerlinBoss..Whats do I put instead on window.ready

Comment: what is `var`, are you using PHP? 'location.Href not working in project' does not convey that..

Comment: did you tried hard coding the URL?

Comment: when you want this loading thing to appear ?

Comment: @CerlinBoss When the page loads and before the content is loaded

Comment: @Sridhar..I am using Ruby on Rails at the backend

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 if (window.location.href==url)
```

instead of

```
if (location.href==url)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ignoring window ready, using only document ready

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.href === url){
        // $(window).ready(function(){
            $('#loadIndicator1').fadeOut(1000);
            return false;
        // });
    }
});
```

You should remove the part I have commented out. The problem is, you attached an event handler to document ready, and if your are on a specific URL, you attach an event handler to window ready, but that event was already fired, and it won't be fired again.

#### Using window load after document ready

Another possible solution:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.href === url){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#loadIndicator1').fadeOut(1000);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

The window load event fires later, than document ready - though this should be tested.

#### Ignoring document ready, using only window load

Third time is a charm, another solution which may be the best, simply ignore the document ready event, and only use the window load:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    if (window.location.href === url) {
        $('#loadIndicator1').fadeOut(1000);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This case though the loader only appears if everything is loaded on the page, so maybe this is not what you want -- in this case use the first option.

Comment: @meskobalazs..Can you please tell me why I am getting unresolved variable location when I hover on location in the above code

Comment: I fixed it, location is a member of the `window` variable.

Comment: @meskobalazs..I have tried all of the above but still not working..I am still not sure why I am getting unresolved variable location when I hover on location..Is it some kind of a problem..I do know that location always refers to window..but am not getting the output in this case

Comment: Could you set up an example we could see? That way I could provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://localhost:3500/#!/Movies";
$(function(){
    if (location.href==url){
        $(window).load(function(){ 
            $('#loadIndicator1').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
});
```

this will show your loader once the webpage is fully downloaded

use `$('#loadIndicator1').fadeOut(1000);` to hide the loader once the content is loaded.